# * is c++ function name?

Tags: c++, function

While browsing the Genode source code documentation, I came across a function who's name started with an asterisk (*), specifically,

```
Hello::Session_component *_create_session(const char *args)
```

I typically work in C, not C++ so am a little confused by this. Is this a pointer to a function named _create_session(), is the * part of the function name, or something else completely?

You can find the code example [here](http://genode.org/documentation/developer-resources/client_server_tutorial).

Comment: `*` has the exact same meaning in C and C++ for the code that you have presented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function is named _create_session, and its return type is a pointer to a Hello::Session_component.

This works just as it does in C:

```
T *func();  // return type is T*
T* func();  // exact same declaration
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this is what I thought was happening, but didn't want to make an ass out of u and me. ('assume' joke)

Answer (score 5):

The `*` refers to the return type not the method name, in this case it returns a `Hello::Session_component*`, so a pointer to a `Session_component`.